# How to Prevent Lizards from Entering Screened-In Patio with Thin-Bolted Aluminum Door?

Tags: exterior, patio

I'm seeking advice on effectively blocking lizards from entering my screened-in patio. I don't want to kill the lizards, I just want them to stop getting into the screened-in patio and getting stuck, then dying. The door uses thin bolts, which might limit my options. I'd like a solution that allows me to open and close the door as usual. Given that it's an aluminum patio door, I'm uncertain about drilling new holes. Pictures attached.

Climate is central Florida.

Any tips or product recommendations would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Comment: my cat takes care of that

Comment: Life will find a way.... and so will lizards.

Comment: try giving the lizards a way out

Comment: So block the holes?

Comment: give the door a gentle but sharp kick with the side of your shoe before opening; that should scare them away momentarily. I would also put an owl statue by the door.

Answer (score 3):

I've lived in Fla for almost 40 years.  No matter what you do, no matter how you seal a door, they will run in when the door is opened.

It's part of Florida, like sunshine and Disneyland. It won't go away.

Besides, the lizards eat bugs.

Comment: I don’t go through the door very often - so if I can prevent it except for those times that would be awesome!